# resize only bigger gif than 250px

Tags: linux, imagemagick, gif, imagemagick-convert

i want to resize only images that have bigger height or bigger width than 250px

but save aspect ratio 
for png and jpg files i use this

```
mogrify -resize '250x250>' *.jpg
```

for gif is not working coz it crop only the first image of gif

i have tried

```
gifsicle --resize '250x250>' --batch  *.gif
```

and i get results like this

**gifsicle: invalid dimensions ‘250x250>’ (want WxH)**

because **>** is not acepted

Answer (score 0):

For gifsicle, use `--resize-fit widthxheight`

`gifsicle --resize-fit '250x250' --batch  *.gif`

From https://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/man.html :

> The aspect ratio remains unchanged. The --resize-fit option only shrinks the image—no resize is performed if the GIF already fits within the rectangle.

Comment: image dont need to be 250 x 250
only if width or height is more than 250 then resize it to 250 and dont lose the aspect ratio

Comment: ?. That's what that does, per the manpage linked: "The --resize-fit option only shrinks the image—no resize is performed if the GIF already fits within the rectangle."